# How to use URL Python Django

Tags: python, django, url

I'm trying to learn Python Django with book **"Example_Build_powerful_and_reliable_Python_web_applications" by Antonio Mele.**
Really sorry for probably stupid questions, but i'm very new.
And sorry for my English, it isn't my native language.

Have some problem with one of the example from the book.
Do the same things as in the book, but URL's dont work.

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'draft'),
    ('published', 'published')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                             choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                             default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                    args=[self.publish.year,
                    self.publish.month,
                    self.day, self.slug])
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
        posts = Post.published.all
        return render(request,
                     'blog/post/list.html',
                     {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name ='blog'

urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
 path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',
 views.post_detail,
 name='post_detail'),
]
```

**BASE.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <h2>My Blog</h2>
      <p>This is my blog</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**LIST.HTML**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My blog{% endblock%}

{% block content %}
  <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
      <h2>
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
      </h2>
      <p class="date">
        Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
      </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

**DETAIL.HTML**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ post.title }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> {{ post.title }} </h1>
  <p class = "date">
    Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
  </p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
  {% endblock %}
```

Also add my urls to URLS here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZVH4.png)

The problem is: when i click on posts on the page BASE.HTML i dont see correct URL and nothing is happening:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPx1Q.png)
Really break my brain.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Problem: when i click on post on the page base.html nothing is happening.

Comment: what is the problem that actually you are facing? and what is your expected output?

Comment: @Sheri update my topic with the problem decription

Answer (score 0):

Your VIEWS.py should contain the methods post(self,request) OR get(self,request) to be callable from the rendered HTML. The methods post_list(..) OR post_detail(..) are not callable on the Django framework.

Comment: Hi Ali. Can you please provide an example? Why i cant use methods post_list and post_detail? it is the example from book "Example_Build_powerful_and_reliable_Python_web_applications" by Antonio Mele.

Comment: Going through this class based views intro will help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Answer (score 0):

Oh my f...ng god.

If somebody will face with the same problem..

**In MODELS.PY** just need to move Class Meta and 2 defs:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'draft'),
    ('published', 'published')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                             choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                             default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                    args=[self.publish.year,
                    self.publish.month,
                    self.day, self.slug])
```

And then in will work good.
Very stupid mistake, so hard to find this..